# Absolute permittivity and permeability of free space

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, induction

I'm reading about the propagation of EM waves in vacuum.

We define the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation) using two constants: $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$. Of course they are [absolute permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) and [absolute permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29) of free space. I've read they have capacitive and inductive properties, I want to know how do we describe it **physically**?

Or, if I could put it this way: I want to understand the purpose of the inductive and capacitive properties of these constants in the propagation of the waves.

Comment: Notice that $c = 1/\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}$. Therefore, the speed of light depends on those parameters. If the vacuum would have infinite capacity and zero inductivity, light would propagate infinitely fast, I'd say. This is just a thought, not a proper answer, though.

Comment: Of course.My concern is the need of conceptualizing it in terms of permittivity and permeability.I'm more interested in propagation itself and not the speed of it.

Comment: I see. That is the point where I do not have much intuition either, so I am looking forward to an answer as well :-)